# SQL Server 2005 - Format a decimal number with leading zeros (including signed decimals!)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, format, signed, financial

I need to format numbers like:-

```
1.99
21.34
1797.94
-300.36
-21.99
-2.31
```

Into a format mask of 0000.00, using SQL-Server 2005 T-SQL. Preserving the signed integers and the decimals after the dot.  This would be used for text file exports for a financial system. It requires it to be in this format.

e.g.-

```
0001.99
0021.34
1794.94
-0300.36
-0021.99
-0002.31
```

Previously, it was done in MS Access as `Format([Total],"0000.00")` but SQL-Server doesn't have this function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
;WITH t(c) AS
(
SELECT 1.99 UNION ALL 
SELECT 21.34  UNION ALL 
SELECT 1797.94  UNION ALL 
SELECT -300.36  UNION ALL 
SELECT -21.99  UNION ALL 
SELECT -2.31 
)
SELECT  
     CASE WHEN SIGN(c) = 1 THEN '' 
          ELSE '-' 
     END + REPLACE(STR(ABS(c), 7, 2), ' ','0') 
FROM t
```

Returns

```
0001.99
0021.34
1797.94
-0300.36
-0021.99
-0002.31
```

Comment: You always have a good CTE.  I had a nice one for Oracle yesterday, recursively tracing invoices through the system (parent / child relationship)

Comment: Thanks Martin! Your solution was the one I was most looking for. It's very elegant!

Answer (score 1):

You could make a function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].padzeros 
(
    @money MONEY,
    @length INT
)
RETURNS varchar(100)
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Dan Andrews
-- Create date: 05/12/11
-- Description: Pad 0's
--
-- =============================================
-- select dbo.padzeros(-2.31,7)
BEGIN

DECLARE @strmoney VARCHAR(100), 
        @result VARCHAR(100)

SET @strmoney = CAST(ABS(@money) AS VARCHAR(100))
SET @result = REPLICATE('0',@length-LEN(@strmoney)) + @strmoney
IF @money < 0 
    SET @result = '-' + RIGHT(@result, LEN(@result)-1)

RETURN @result

END
```

example:

```
select dbo.padzeros(-2.31,7)
```

Comment: I didn't notice that you didn't want to keep the length the same (neg character takes a space).  You can just concatenate '-' to the string instead of doing the RIGHT

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for the code. Yeah, its odd that the sign takes up a space like you say, instead of being totally fixed-width. It's for an old Cobol based financial system. :-/

Comment: I do some contract work in the evenings programming in FORTRAN on a DEC Alpha... yeah... I feel your pain.  I probably could rewrite their whole system in .NET and it would run better and be more functional, but consulting FORTRAN developers make more than consulting .NET developers.  :)  Besides, it reminds me of the days when programming was magical.