# Pad Varchar with 0 in SQL Server 2005

Tags: mysql, select, pad

I have tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760900/pad-a-string-with-leading-zeros-so-its-3-characters-long-in-sql-server-2008) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979204/sql-server-2005-format-a-decimal-number-with-leading-zeros-including-signed-d) as I need to pad a column with zeros.

So I have a field

```
name_id
1
2
21
74
```

And I want it to be like

```
name_id
001
002
021
074
```

So I have tried doing this:

```
SELECT RIGHT('000'+ name_id,3) from tblCoordinates;
```

But the result is:

```
RIGHT('000'+name_id,3)
1
2
21
74
```

I am using MySQL Server 2005. What is wrong with select statement? Thanks

Comment: Your code is correct.  Where are you seeing the non-padded values?

Comment: `SELECT '000' + 1` => 1, implicit conversion

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert `name_id` to `VARCHAR` first:

```
SELECT RIGHT('000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), name_id), 3) from tblCoordinates;
```

If you're using MySQL, there is a built-in function [`LPAD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad)

```
SELECT LPAD(name_id, 3, '0') from tblCoordinates;
```

Comment: if i do that, I am getting this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'name_id), 3) from tblCoordinates' at line 1

Comment: Try using `CAST` instead.

Comment: do i still need to convert the name_id to varchar even if the data type is varchar already?

Comment: @user3201441 No, you don't have to convert anything. Concatenating string using `CONCAT(...)`

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT '000' + '1'` => 1
For concatenation use **`CONCAT()`**

```
SELECT RIGHT(CONCAT('000',name_id),3)
FROM tblCoordinates;
```

Comment: having an error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NVARCHAR(10)),3)' at line 1. Again I am using 2005 version of MySql

Comment: You use MySQL and you tag question as sql-server.

Comment: @user3201441 Give data example and look at this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9eecb7db/22